# How to create a dynamic folium marker

Tags: python, flask, leaflet, folium, htmx

Please I need help with folium and flask. I am building a satellite tracking web app that uses an api from n2yo.com(https://www.n2yo.com/api/) to get it's data. It asks for the Norad id and period of the satellite then displays it's position and path on a map. I am trying to update the marker just like the way it does on the website every time the satellite moves to a new location. Now that is where I am stuck. When i tried using htmx, I did not like the fact that htmx was refreshing the whole map with the marker, I only want the folium marker object to update. Please help me out Below are my codes.

Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, render_template_string
import requests
import json
import folium
from folium.plugins import AntPath, Fullscreen



app = Flask(__name__)
LAT = 6.524379
LON = 3.379206
ALT = 10
# SECONDS = 2500
APIKEY = "An_api_key"




@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = request.form["id"]
        period = request.form["period"]
        return redirect(f"/data/{id}/{period}")
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/data/<int:id>/<period>")
def data(id, period):
    periods = float(period)
    periods = periods*60
    content = requests.get(f'https://api.n2yo.com/rest/v1/satellite/positions/{id}/{LAT}/{LON}/{ALT}/{periods}/&apiKey={APIKEY}').content
    content = content.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    path = "static/assets/sat.png"
    my_json = json.loads(content)
    pos = my_json["positions"]
    posi =pos[0]
    lat = posi["satlatitude"]
    long = posi["satlongitude"]
    azimuth = posi["azimuth"]
    elevation = posi["elevation"]
    altitude = posi["sataltitude"]
    name = my_json["info"]["satname"]

    # Calculate the custom path
    pathlist = [(pos[p]["satlatitude"], pos[p]["satlongitude"]) for p in range(len(pos) - 1)] 
    satellite_map = folium.Map(location=[LAT,LON], tiles = "cartodb positron", zoom_start=1,world_copy_jump=True, width=600, height=600)
    custom_icon = folium.CustomIcon(icon_image=path, icon_size=(30, 30))
    folium.Marker(
        location=[lat, long], popup='Satellite Position', icon=custom_icon).add_to(satellite_map)
    Fullscreen(
    title='Expand me',
    title_cancel='Exit fullscreen',
    force_separate_button=True
).add_to(satellite_map)
    AntPath(pathlist, delay=400, weight=3, color = "red", dash_array = [30,15], loop = False).add_to(satellite_map)
    satellite_map.get_root().render()
    iframe = satellite_map.get_root()._repr_html_()
    if 'hx_request' in request.headers:
       return render_template("map.html", iframe = iframe, id=id, latitude = lat, longitude=long, azimuth=azimuth, elevation=elevation, altitude=altitude, name=name, period=period)
    return render_template("data.html", iframe = iframe, id=id, latitude = lat, longitude=long, azimuth=azimuth, elevation=elevation, altitude=altitude, name=name, period=period)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80,debug=True)
```

Note: You have to put an api key to get it working. Don't worry the api is free. :)

Also note: I am using an image(png) for the marker. so you can disregard icon argument in the marker method.

Templates

data.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Satellite Tracking Map </title>


</head>

<body>
    <h1>Satellite Tracking Map ({{id}}) {{name}}</h1>

    <div>

        <div style="position: relative;">
            <div hx-get="/data/{{id}}/{{period}}" hx-trigger="every 5s" hx-target="#update">{{iframe | safe}}</div>
            <span id="update">
                {%include 'map.html'%}
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>






    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.5"
        integrity="sha384-xcuj3WpfgjlKF+FXhSQFQ0ZNr39ln+hwjN3npfM9VBnUskLolQAcN80McRIVOPuO"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

map.html

```
<div id="overlay"
    style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;">
    <h3>Satellite Data</h3>
    <p>Latitude: {{latitude}}</p>
    <p>Longitude: {{longitude}}</p>
    <p>Altitude: {{altitude}}</p>
    <p>Azimuth: {{azimuth}}</p>
    <p>Elevation: {{elevation}}</p>
</div>
```

Thank you to whoever helps me solve this :)

Comment: Can you take a look at htmx extension `multi-swap` extension, I believe it best suits your need. https://htmx.org/extensions/multi-swap/

Comment: Thank you @McPherson  I have taken a look at it but i have 1 question, I am finding it difficult to know the markers' id to multiswap given that folium creates a unique marker id every time. So please any idea how i am going to get that? I tried using some javascript but it kept returning null for my variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multi-swap` htmx [extension](https://htmx.org/extensions/multi-swap/). After registering it, try putting the variables in the `maps.html` into their own tags with ID attributes.

```
<div id="overlay"
    style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05); padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;">
    <h3>Satellite Data</h3>
    <p>Latitude: <span id="latitude">{{latitude}}</span></p>
    <p>Longitude: <span id="longitude">{{longitude}}</span></p>
    <p>Altitude: <span id="altitude">{{altitude}}</span></p>
    <p>Azimuth: <span id="azimuth">{{azimuth}}</span></p>
    <p>Elevation: <span id="elevation">{{elevation}}</span</p>
</div>
```

Then in your htmx request in `data.html`,

```
<div hx-swap="multi:#latitude,#longitude,#altitude,#azimuth,#elevation" hx-get="/data/{{id}}/{{period}}" hx-trigger="every 5s">{{iframe | safe}}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @McPherson. This doesn't update the marker position only, and besides it seems to write the new values on the existing ones in the satellite data column. The thing is there's a map in that {{iframe | safe }} and in that map there's a bunch of js code that controls various things like the marker. What i really want is for the marker alone to be updating its position with htmx without refreshing the map. so if only they was a way for me to get the marker's id, I could run the htmx multiswap on that id with the new latitude and longitude data i get from the server or what do you think?

Comment: Oh, in that case, my solution would indeed not work. I am unfamiliar with folium so I will need to look at its documentation. Otherwise, I have no idea how.

Comment: Okay thanks for the attempt and time.